# R: factanal() function returning "unable to optimize from this starting value"

Tags: r

I got a data frame with 627 observations of 11 variables, all of them numeric (whit distinct ranges). I try to apply to it a factorial analysis with the `factanal` function, but occasionaly I receive the "unable to optimize from this starting value" error message. See, for instance, the following situations:

- Try 3 or more factors, lower = 0.005

  Error message
- Try 6 factors, lower = 0.006

  No error message. P-Value = 0.02.
- Try 3 or 4 factor, lower = 0.006

  Error message

If I, for example, fix the number of factors at five, and start putting very low values fo the `lower` paramether, it will work for some particular values, but not for others (no patterns followed). I think I'll go ahead with `6` factors, but can somebody explain why this behavior?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146141/error-in-factor-analysis-starting-values